# install jar file in dbfs and mvn packages using init script

Tags: initialization, databricks, azure-databricks

I have few Jar files/packages in the DBFS and I want an init script (so that I can place that in the automated cluster) to install the Jar package everytime the cluster starts.

I also want to install maven packages from maven using an init script.

I can do all of these using databricks UI. But the requirement is to install libraries using an init script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install jar files, just put files onto DBFS, in some location, and in the init script do:

```
cp /dbfs/<some-location>/*.jar /databricks/jars/
```

Installation of the maven dependencies is more tricky, because you also will need to fetch dependencies.  But it's doable - from the init script:

- Download and unpack [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)
- Execute:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=<maven_coordinates>
```

- move downloaded jars:

```
find ~/.m2/repository/ -name \*.jar -print0|xargs -0 mv -t /databricks/jars/
```

- (optional) remove not necessary directory:

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/
```

P.S. But really, I recommend to automate such stuff via [Databricks Terraform Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs).

Comment: I used wget to retrieve jars from mvn and placed them in /databricks/jars/

Comment: wget won't handle transitive dependencies...  Also, take into account that by using `/dbfs/` you may have some problems, so you check if your init scripts executed correctly

Comment: @AlexOtt Does jar needs to have a specific name once they are in /databricks/jars/ on the driver (for example a single node)  ?

Comment: I'm having trouble to install gresearch and use it in my python notebooks

Comment: no, they just need to have `.jar` extension

Comment: That what I was thinking. Weird that nothing is detected only for jars but the jars are on the driver (using web terminal). I'll post something if I don't manage it :), thanks !

Comment: I managed it for other jars but for this library I can't make it work: https://github.com/G-Research/spark-extension. I tried your maven solution (adding some execution user rights too) but it didn't work neither. If you have any idea ?

Comment: check that you have version for corresponding Spark version

Comment: I thought it was that at first too. I'm using: spark-extension_2.12-2.0.0-3.2.jar, scala 2.12 and spark 3.2, on a cluster with DBR 10.1 (Spark 3.2 - Scala 2.12). Is there any command I could run on my cluster to check if the jar can be used ? It maybe needs other libraries to run :/

Comment: just print a classpath - obtain it from the system properties

Comment: I can find it in the classpath, so it should be known. Mmmh....

Comment: What is the command to execute some spark code on a node ? Obviously it doesn't know pyspark or sbt. Should I use something like python -m pyspark XXX ? I'd like to point directly to my jar to see if I can have an error more explicit

Comment: As a shortcut for the three steps `mvn dependency:get`, `find`, and `rm`, you could do `mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=<maven_coordinates> -DoutputDirectory=/databricks/jars/`

Comment: Really, it's not as simple because we need to remove not necessary jars, like, Spark, Scala, etc.

Comment: @AlexOtt You mention above *"wget won't handle transitive dependencies... Also, take into account that by using /dbfs/ you may have some problems, so you check if your init scripts executed correctly"* but don't specify an alternative in your answer here.  What do you recommend if not wget?

Comment: No alternatives  really when using wget… you can use maven to fetch dependencies

Comment: Is this `/databricks/jars` officially documented anywhere?