# How to check if a class is installed on Databricks through a Spark Listener?

Tags: java, azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

Using a Spark Listener on Databricks, I am trying to see if a given class is installed but given Databricks' way of installing packages, the Listener cannot see packages installed after the cluster has been started.

**In a Java Spark Listener, is there a better way to recognize that a class is installed for packages installed via Databricks' Libraries API / UI?**

### Summary

- Using a SparkListener installed via a [cluster-scoped init script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html) on Databricks.
- Using [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)  in the Listener to check if a given class is installed.
- On Apache Spark

  - Works on Apache Spark if the Listener is installed via `--packages` or `--jars`.
  - Fails on Apache Spark if the Listener is installed via `--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath` and the desired libraries were installed via `--packages` or `--jars`.
- On (Azure) Databricks

  - Works on Databricks if the library already exists in the `/datbaricks/jars` directory which is the `$CLASSPATH` directory.
  - Fails on Databricks if the library is installed via the Libraries API / UI (jars installed this way seem to end up at `/local_disk0/tmp`).

### Spark Listener Details

With Apache Spark, I can install a Spark Listener via `--packages` + `--conf spark.extraListeners=listener.MyListener` and leverage a [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) in the Spark Listener to check for any class installed through `--jars`, `--packages`, or on the class path.  The listener to detect if a class exists looks like this.

```java
public class MyListener extends org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("MyLogger");
  @Override
  public void onJobStart(SparkListenerJobStart jobStart) {
    try{
      log.info("Trying LogicalRelation");
      MyListener.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(
      "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation"
      );
      log.info("Got logical relation");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
      log.info("Couldn't find LogicalRelation");
    }

    try{
      log.info("Trying org.apache.iceberg.catalog.Catalog");
      MyListener.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("org.apache.iceberg.catalog.Catalog");
      log.info("Got org.apache.iceberg.catalog.Catalog!!!!");
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
      log.info("Could not get org.apache.iceberg.catalog.Catalog");
    }

    try{
      log.info("Trying Kusto DefaultSource");
      MyListener.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource.DefaultSource");
      log.info("Got Kusto DefaultSource!!!!");
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
      log.info("Could not get Kusto DefaultSource");
    }
  }
}
```

On Databricks, the listener is installed via an init script that looks like:

```bash
cp -f /dbfs/databricks/custom/listener.jar /mnt/driver-daemon/jars || { echo "Error"; exit 1;}

cat << 'EOF' > /databricks/driver/conf/customer-listener.conf
[driver] {
  "spark.extraListeners" = "listener.MyListener"
}
EOF
```

This installation approach is similar to other public listeners:

- [MSFT Spark Monitoring](https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring/blob/main/README.md#configure-the-databricks-workspace)
- [SO response from Databricks Employee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70974028/addsparklistener-equivalent-in-databricks)

#### Attempted to use URLClassLoader

It seems that the [Scala ClassLoader doesn't play nicely with a Java classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671888/scala-classloaders-confusion). I attempted to add a [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) as per another [SO post on setting a different classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724481/set-classloader-different-directory) but the ClassNotFoundException continues.

This code on a Databricks Interactive notebook, however, does successfully find my test classes

```java
URLClassLoader ucl;
    try {
      log.info("URL Class Loader Attempt V3");
      File file = new File("/local_disk0/tmp/");
      URL classUrl = file.toURI().toURL();
      URL[] urls = new URL[] { classUrl };
      System.out.println(urls.toString());
      ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls, getClass().getClassLoader());
      ucl.loadClass("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource.DefaultSource");
      try {
        ucl.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Failed to close url classloader");
      }
      log.info("GOT KustoLIBRARY with URL Class Loader!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // Still hitting this one
      log.info("Could not get Kusto Library with URLClassLoader");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      log.info("The URL was malformed");
    }
```

### Databricks Library Details

With Databricks, the majority of users use the [Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/) feature which installs jars AFTER spark has started and allows for users to easily install a jar via the Databricks UI or through an API.

When using the above listener and the `ClassLoader` it will consistently raise a `ClassNotFoundException` for packages installed via the Libraries API.

In the Databricks logs, I can see the desired jar being installed in the logs.

```
22/07/14 13:32:34 INFO DriverCorral: [Thread 123] AttachLibraries - candidate libraries: List(JavaJarId(dbfs:/FileStore/jars/maven/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/kusto-spark_3.0_2.12-3.0.0.jar,,NONE)
22/07/14 13:32:34 INFO DriverCorral: [Thread 123] AttachLibraries - new libraries to install (including resolved dependencies): List(JavaJarId(dbfs:/FileStore/jars/maven/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/kusto-spark_3.0_2.12-3.0.0.jar,,NONE))
22/07/14 13:32:37 INFO SharedDriverContext: [Thread 123] attachLibrariesToSpark JavaJarId(dbfs:/FileStore/jars/maven/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/kusto-spark_3.0_2.12-3.0.0.jar,,NONE)
22/07/14 13:32:37 INFO LibraryDownloadManager: Downloading a library that was not in the cache: JavaJarId(dbfs:/FileStore/jars/maven/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/kusto-spark_3.0_2.12-3.0.0.jar,,NONE)
22/07/14 13:32:37 INFO LibraryDownloadManager: Attempt 1: wait until library JavaJarId(dbfs:/FileStore/jars/maven/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/kusto-spark_3.0_2.12-3.0.0.jar,,NONE) is downloaded
22/07/14 13:32:37 INFO LibraryDownloadManager: Downloaded library JavaJarId(dbfs:/FileStore/jars/maven/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/kusto-spark_3.0_2.12-3.0.0.jar,,NONE) as local file /local_disk0/tmp/addedFile2043314239110388521kusto_spark_3_0_2_12_3_0_0-6add9.jar in 39 milliseconds
22/07/14 13:32:37 INFO SharedDriverContext: Successfully saved library JavaJarId(dbfs:/FileStore/jars/maven/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/kusto-spark_3.0_2.12-3.0.0.jar,,NONE) to local file /local_disk0/tmp/addedFile2043314239110388521kusto_spark_3_0_2_12_3_0_0-6add9.jar
22/07/14 13:32:37 INFO SharedDriverContext: Successfully attached library dbfs:/FileStore/jars/maven/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/kusto-spark_3.0_2.12-3.0.0.jar to Spark
22/07/14 13:32:37 INFO LibraryState: [Thread 123] Successfully attached library dbfs:/FileStore/jars/maven/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/kusto-spark_3.0_2.12-3.0.0.jar
```

If I were to install the desired jar/package and all of it's dependencies into the `/databricks/jars` folder, the Spark Listener can successfully detect that the packages are installed.  [Confirmed by Databricks Employee on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66431231/install-jar-file-in-dbfs-and-mvn-packages-using-init-script). However, this is not a common practice given the Databricks Libraries feature.

So, it all seems to boil down to: How do I get the main ClassLoader on a Databricks interactive or job clusters to recognize libraries installed via the Spark Application context (as seen in the Libraries API / UI)?

Thank you for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("<class_name>")` instead of `MyListener.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("<class_name>")` appears to work as required in this case.

The [Apache Spark implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L208-L237) also uses `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader`.

The following Stack Overflow posts are helpful for understanding the difference between the two approaches:

- [Difference between thread's context class loader and normal classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1771679/11551392)
- [Difference between Thread.currentThread() classLoader and normal classLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40303433/11551392)

This [article](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077344/find-a-way-out-of-the-classloader-maze.html) also seems to have even more information about the different types of classLoaders in Java.

Hope this helps!